# Как злоумышленник может развернуть свой маршрутизатор на данном участке?

Tags: linux, маршрутизация, cisco, ospf

Имеется следующий участок:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Развернув на данном участке маршрутизатор, есть риск навязывания ложной маршрутной информации.  Каким образом злоумышленник может развернуть на данном участке свой маршрутизатор? И как это можно предотвратить?

Comment: Ну например, включиться своим маршрутизатором в свитч (который в центре красного круга). Предотвратить... заблокировать на свиче все порты и поднимать их только по предъявлению паспорта и автографа в спец.журнале.

Comment: Да, и для полноты вопроса надо осветить тему "в чем цель злоумышленника".

Comment: Я так понимаю, если он развернёт там свой роутер, то он сможет навязать ложную маршрутную информацию, верно?

Comment: Если речь про то, что злоумышленник переключит все конечные хосты этого сетевого сегмента в свой маршрутизатор (по факту - выдернет пачкорды из свича и воткнет в свой маршрутизатор), то чего-то может и навяжет в рамках этого сегмента. Либо у роутера злоумышленника будет свой независимый канал мимо роутера 10.0.1.1. Тогда будут другие варианты. Но в целом вопрос больше для [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com) - там сетевые гуру в большей концентрации.

Comment: надо просто заблокировать протоколы динамической маршрутизации на порту смотрящем в сеть где других маршрутизаторов не подразумевается. или сделать то же самое на свитче, если на нем есть ACL. И вообще заблочить динамичекую маршрутизацию на всех портах кроме тех к которым подключены маршрутизаторы

Comment: Лаер3 фильтр, запретить серверные dhcp запросы/реквесты (широковещательные), по другому на этот маршрутизатор никто сам не пойдет.

Answer (score 0):

Есть смысл включить и добавить авторизацию по ключам:

```
    ip ospf authentication-key YourSescretKey
```

Подробности [тут](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/open-shortest-path-first-ospf/13697-25.html)